# Theme Convert PHP code to shortcode

Tags: shortcode

My theme uses this code which I am trying to convert to a shortcode so I can use on custom templates:

```
<div class="x-breadcrumb-wrap">
      <div class="x-container max width">

        <?php x_breadcrumbs(); ?>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I know I have to add a shortcode like this to my `functions.php` but can't figure out the syntax.

```
add_shortcode( 'mycrumbs', 'mytest_breadcrumbs' );
```

UPDATE:

For easy of use I only need to call the function x_breadcrumbs. My theme defines this function as:

```
function x_breadcrumbs() {

    if ( x_get_option( 'x_breadcrumb_display' ) ) {

      GLOBAL $post;

      $is_ltr         = ! is_rtl();
      $stack          = x_get_stack();
      $delimiter      = x_get_breadcrumb_delimiter();
      $home_text      = x_get_breadcrumb_home_text();
      $home_link      = home_url();
      $current_before = x_get_breadcrumb_current_before();
      $current_after  = x_get_breadcrumb_current_after();
      $page_title     = get_the_title();
      $blog_title     = get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts', true ) );

      if ( ! is_404() ) {
        $post_parent = $post->post_parent;
      } else {
        $post_parent = '';
      }

      if ( X_WOOCOMMERCE_IS_ACTIVE ) {
        $shop_url   = x_get_shop_link();
        $shop_title = x_get_option( 'x_' . $stack . '_shop_title' );
        $shop_link  = '<a href="'. $shop_url .'">' . $shop_title . '</a>';
      }

      echo '<div class="x-breadcrumbs"><a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $home_text . '</a>' . $delimiter;

        if ( is_home() ) {

          echo $current_before . $blog_title . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_category() ) {

          $the_cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ), false );
          if ( $the_cat->parent != 0 ) echo get_category_parents( $the_cat->parent, TRUE, $delimiter );
          echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_product_category() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product_tag() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( is_search() ) {

          echo $current_before . __( 'Search Results for ', '__x__' ) . '&#8220;' . get_search_query() . '&#8221;' . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

          if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) == is_front_page() ) {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            if ( $is_ltr ) {
              echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">' . $blog_title . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
            } else {
              echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">' . $blog_title . '</a>';
            }
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio() ) {

          echo $current_before . get_the_title() . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio_item() ) {

          $link  = x_get_parent_portfolio_link();
          $title = x_get_parent_portfolio_title();

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>';
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_buddypress() ) {

          if ( bp_is_group() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . bp_get_groups_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_groups_title' ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          } elseif ( bp_is_user() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . bp_get_members_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_members_title' ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_bbpress() ) {

          remove_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

          if ( bbp_is_forum_archive() ) {
            echo $current_before . bbp_get_forum_archive_title() . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo bbp_get_breadcrumb();
          }

          add_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

        } elseif ( is_page() && ! $post_parent ) {

          echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_page() && $post_parent ) {

          $parent_id   = $post_parent;
          $breadcrumbs = array();

          if ( is_rtl() ) {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter;
          }

          while ( $parent_id ) {
            $page          = get_page( $parent_id );
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $page->ID ) . '</a>';
            $parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse( $breadcrumbs );
          }

          for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $breadcrumbs ); $i++ ) {
            echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
            if ( $i != count( $breadcrumbs ) -1 ) echo $delimiter;
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          }

        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

          echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_author() ) {

          GLOBAL $author;
          $userdata = get_userdata( $author );
          echo $current_before . __( 'Posts by ', '__x__' ) . '&#8220;' . $userdata->display_name . $current_after . '&#8221;';

        } elseif ( is_404() ) {

          echo $current_before . __( '404 (Page Not Found)', '__x__' ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_archive() ) {

          if ( x_is_shop() ) {
            echo $current_before . $shop_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . __( 'Archives ', '__x__' ) . $current_after;
          }

        }

      echo '</div>';

    }

  }
endif;
```

Comment: Are there versions of your x_ functions that return values instead of echoing them?

Comment: please see update..

Comment: @JoannaMikalai your new code will have to be wrapped in `ob_*()` functions again, the reason for this is that both your codes, 1st and 2nd one produce output, but shortcodes must not produce output (see add_shortcode docs), so you have to capture output with `ob_start` and then save if with `ob_get_clean()` then return it, this is the only way you can do it. Or you will have to rewrite the function removing any `echo` or similar, and this seems doable for your function. One drawback, if the original function is improved by the theme author, will you keep track of that and modify your code?

Comment: And again, `ob_*` is safe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php it becomes dangerous if not used currectly, as any code in any language.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, I used output buffering with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Breadcrumbs based on theme's functions
 *
 * @author  Nabil Kadimi <nabil@kadimi.com>
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/242547/17187
 */
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_shortcode( 'mycrumbs', function() {

        /**
         * Start capturing output.
         */
        ob_start();

        ?>
        <div class="x-breadcrumb-wrap">
            <div class="x-container max width">
                <?php x_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                <?php if ( is_single() || x_is_portfolio_item() ) : ?>
                    <?php x_entry_navigation(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?

        /**
         * Stop capturing output and return what was captured to WordPress.
         */
        return ob_get_clean();

    } ); // add_shortcode( 'mycrumbs', closure );
} ); // add_action( 'init', closure );
```

Comment: Someone told me to avoid ob_start - what is the purpose of this?

Comment: i am getting white screen of death with this code

Comment: Make sure you have a supported version of PHP (5.6 or 7, although 5.4 should support that code), check your error logs for errors or turn on WordPress debugging to see what is the error. I can't suggest a fix if I don't know the error.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai the point of the output buffering is to get around your x_ functions echoing output but a shortcode function needing to return a value instead. You're right that output buffering is frowned upon, I believe because it will cause problems in some circumstances if two plugins both try and use it.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai And output buffering is perfectly safe if done correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
function mytest_breadcrumbs() {

$crumbs ='<div class="x-breadcrumb-wrap"><div class="x-container max width">';
$crumbs.=x_breadcrumbs();
if ( is_single() || x_is_portfolio_item() ) {
$crumbs.=x_entry_navigation();
}
$crumbs.='</div></div>';


    // Code
return $crumbs;
}
add_shortcode( 'mycrumbs', 'mytest_breadcrumbs' );
```

then call in page with 
[mycrumbs]

Comment: But the x_ functions don't return values according to the OP's original code.

Comment: i dont' know what those functions look like but the error i get when i run is that i can't find the x_functions, which is exactly as I would expect since i don't have them.    i dont' link ob_start either but it may be the only solution.  I'll wait until OP replies and then comment further if the above doesn't work

Comment: please see update of my question..

Comment: did my solution work?